# Google Maps CameraPosition Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

When I use the CameraPositionState members isMoving and cameraMoveStartedReason, Google Maps freezes and stops responding. My goal is to do some work after the map is moved by gesture.

```
                val singapore = LatLng(1.35, 103.87)
                val cameraPositionState: CameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
                    position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(singapore, 11f)
                }

                if(cameraPositionState.isMoving &&
                    cameraPositionState.cameraMoveStartedReason == CameraMoveStartedReason.GESTURE) {
                    /* TODO */
                }
```

How can I do it better?

Thank you.

Comment: post your component here so we can find out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map freezes because it recomposes while the map moves – which is a LOT btw, you can simply print it in your composable just to check that out. So you're doing some treatment at each recomposition.

You should rather treat it as a side effect instead. The simplest way would be with a `LaunchedEffect`:

```
LaunchedEffect(cameraPositionState.isMoving) {
    if (cameraPositionState.isMoving && cameraPositionState.cameraMoveStartedReason == CameraMoveStartedReason.GESTURE) {
        // Do your work here, it will be done only when the map starts moving from a drag gesture.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to have a look into `derivedStateOf` (also a side effect) that could better address that than a `LaunchedEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative that worked better for me:

```
var currentLatLng: LatLng? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState()
LaunchedEffect(cameraPositionState) {
    snapshotFlow { cameraPositionState.position.target }
        .debounce(200)
        .collect { currentLatLng = it }
}
```

When I attempted to rely on `cameraPositionState.isMoving` I would sometimes not get an update. Another advantage of this approach is that, even if the user has not lifted their finger, `currentLatLng` will be updated if there has been no change for the last 200 milliseconds (e.g., user stopped dragging).

Bear in mind that `debounce` is still in preview and may change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your map freezes because compose always recreate it on camera position change. I have written an article on this topic, you can check out it and also know how it works:

https://towardsdev.com/jetpack-compose-google-map-camera-movement-listener-erselan-khan-5a9d1b223548

output result:

https://youtu.be/S5LV9bbXtzo